# Echo custom taxonomy term name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I would like to echo out the term name from a custom taxonomy `'recipes'` but all I get is the word "recipe" when it should say eg "pizza recipe". Is `name` the right argument here or I am mistaking it for `slug`?

```
<?php
   $term = get_terms( 'recipes' ); 
   echo '<div class="title">' . $term->name . 'recipe</div>';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this and I will post the answer:

```
<?php
  $args = array('number' => '1',);
  $terms = get_terms('recipes', $args );
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
    echo '<div class="title">' . $term->name . 'recipe</div>';
    }
```